# Loading multiple copies of a shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, dlopen

I would like to be able to load multiple copies of a shared library into the same address space.  I want them to not share any global variables, and I want the two copies to be unaware that the other has been loaded.

The use-case is parallel execution of a thread-unsafe library.

How can I do this

- on Linux?
- on OS X?
- on Windows?
- on *BSD?
- on other Unix-like systems?

Answer (score 3):

> The use-case is parallel execution of a thread-unsafe library.

Even if you manage to achieve the "not share any global variables" goal (which is hard), the library may *still* not work, because it could be calling into thread-unsafe routines in *other* libraries.

The obvious case is for the library to call `strtok`.

On Linux and Solaris, you could use `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, ...)`. [Man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0213/6m6ne37t1/index.html).